# Replace to local javascript file when page load using chrome extension manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I want to run my local javascript file instead of server's file.
I'm using manifest v3 on Chrome extension.

My manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Replace js",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "content-script.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "https://mine.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "declarativeNetRequest",
        "declarativeNetRequestFeedback",
        "webRequest",
        "scripting",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://www.mine.com/*"
    ]
}
```

And background.js file

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (details) {
        if (details.url == "https://www.mine.com/remote.js")
            // run my file
    },
    { urls: ["*://www.mine.com/*.js"] },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

But `onBeforeRequest` is deprecated in manifest v3

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You can use [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-UpdateRuleOptions) with `extensionPath` to redirect to the file in your extension. Its relative path+name should be added to [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/). P.S. onBeforeRequest is not deprecated. The blocking mode is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, @wOxxOm. Could you give me detailed example?

Comment: There are many examples for extensionPath around, including the documentation I've linked.